# I am using magento Login code in PopUp and code is not working

Tags: jquery, html, authentication, popup, magento-1.8

I am using **magento** Login code which is to display in a Pop-Up and my code is not working, I wanted to know why it is not working? could anyone help me with this?

**The following is my code I am trying with:**

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>" method="post" id="login-form">

      <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
         <div class="login-popup-content">
            <div class="login-div">
              <div class="login-txt-div">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="register-link">

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">New ? Register</a>
                        </div><!--end of register-link-->
                    </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                    <div class="col-md-6"> <h2><?php echo $this->__('Login in to Your Account') ?></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                       
                        <div class="register-link" style="width: 125px !important;">                            
                            <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">  
                                <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close                       
                            </a>
                        </div><!--end of register-link-->
                    </div>
                 </div><!--end of row-->
               </div><!--end of login-txt-div-->

           <div class="login-detail" >
                <div class="row">

           <div class="uname-detail">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Username</h2>
                        </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="email" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                        </div><!--end of col-md-8-->
                    </div><!--end of uname-detail-->
                </div><!--end of row-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="uname-detail">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Password</h2>
                        </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                        </div><!--end of col-md-8-->
                    </div><!--end of uname-detail-->
                </div><!--end of row-->
            </div>               
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>

            <div class="help-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">     
                            <div class="help-div">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-question"></i>Need help?</span>
                            </div><!--end of help-div-->
                        </div><!--end of col-md-3-->
                        <div class="col-md-3">     
                            <div class="login-btn">
                                <button class="login_bttn" type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                            </div><!--end of loginbtn-->
                        </div><!--end of col-md-3-->
      </form>
```